# How to set camelCase as attributes in HTML element whose namespace belongs to XHTML

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

Is there a way to `setAttribute()` on an element where the attribute **name** can be **camelCase**..!?
eg: 
present: `element.setAttribute("myAttr","myattrValue");`
results: `<p myattr="myattrValue"/>`

Can the attribute be set in the **camelCase**..?
looking for something like: `<p myAttr="myattrValue"/>`
elementNamespaceURI : xhtml/1999

**Edit:**
another example: `<input type="text" onClick="func()"/>` is what I am looking for, where as 
 `<input type="text"/>` will be given as source, and have to setAttribute().. 
 which is **onClick** 
but now it's **onclick**...!

"Onclick", is just an example to showcase, where both `onClick` & `onclick` will yield same result..But the need is attribute **camelCase** as it is set!

Help me find solution...!

Comment: What is purpose of setting uppercase attribute name?

Comment: case is to perform a generic way of attribute access across various frameWorks.
@Mohammad : there is explanation of HTML specs, but not solution/ a workaround.

Comment: Sounds like you just got a habit to kick to me... you keep spelling arbitrary words in camel case for no apparent reason, and if you just stopped doing that you wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: For the record, the XHTML namespace has nothing to do with any of this. HTML elements are always represented as being in the XHTML namespace whether your page is in HTML or XML mode. In fact, were your page in XML mode, you would in fact see myAttr being reflected in the correct case.

Comment: @BoltClock , lolz... apparently I am kicked off with this problem.. :) The solution for this problem can be a mark for any one who is searching for in near future..! ;)

Comment: Neither `myAttr`, `myattr` nor `onClick` are in the XHTML namespace. The first two simply don't exist and `onclick` is explicitly all lower case.

Comment: After all the comments, it's still unclear what you want to achieve. On the one hand it sounds like switching your file type to actual XHTML will result in what you want; you can give elements attributes in the case you want and they won't change case. However, then you start about `onClick`, and, well, giving an element an `onClick` attribute in XHTML won't _do_ anything; it will just be useless garbage. So, what do you want??

Comment: Simply I am trying to set an attribute to a dom element, in camelCase. Which is not happeneing, even if I set, it is converting to lowercase.

Comment: @peaceUser Why do you want that?

Comment: I am afraid that even if I tell the reason n-times like above it will not happen and it seems like a debate topic rather a problem and resolution..!